# upload_max_filesize in .user.ini Not Reflected in Media Upload

Tags: uploads, media-library, php.ini

I would like to know why Media Upload does not detect the **`upload_max_filesize`** that had been set in **`.user.ini`** file as shown below.

```
max_execution_time = 10000
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

---

This is the **`phpinfo.php`**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RHbj.png

---

This is the error message after uploading a 10MB PDF file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIdxq.png

---

I do not want to apply these settings in **`php.ini`** because there are still multiple projects are running inside the server. That is why I prefer to set all the setting in **`user.ini`**.

Any kind soul please help me edit the image link.
Much appreciate.

Comment: Is your `user.ini` file in your `wp-admin` folder?

Comment: Hi @TimMalone, nope. It allocates at root directory.

Comment: Try to place the following two lines into `.htaccess` file:    
`php_value post_max_size 10M` and `php_value upload_max_filesize 10M`

Comment: @Kane Uploads are handled in the wp-admin directory, so try placing it in there. I've had success with placing php.ini files in there on shared hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `@Tim Malone`,

> @Kane Uploads are handled in the wp-admin directory, so try placing it in there. I've had success with placing php.ini files in there on shared hosts. – Tim Malone 1 hour ago

Just place **`.user.ini`** to `/wp-admin` to overwrite the setting.